# Known vulnerabilities in (EC-)KCDSA

Tags: elliptic-curves

Does anybody know if there's known vulnerabilities in KCDSA/EC-KCDSA?

I have been researching for the past few hours and I haven't found anything. Wikipedia has very limited amount of information and based on the original whitepaper everything is rosy as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest Wikipedia as a source of information in the area of crypto...

Comment: Me neither. It's just usually a good place to get started with some links to more "proper" places.

Comment: jimmy, Have you [done a literature search](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/351)?  That's the obvious first step.