# The improvement of the private key exponent in the M.Weiner Attack

Tags: encryption, rsa

I am working on attacks on RSA and came across the M. Weiner attack.

The limit for $d$ in order for the attack to apply is $d <= (\frac{1}{3})N^{0.25}$. The paper states that Boneh and Durfee improved this limit… but to what? What's the limit they reach for the attack to still apply?

Comment: I'd expect you to do more research on your own before asking here (on this site [we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182266/160917)).  In the future, one way to answer this sort of thing on your own is [to do a literature search](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/351).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the abstract:

> Abstract:
>   We show that if the private exponent d used in the RSA system is less than 
>   $N^{0.292}$ then the system is insecure. This is the first improvement of an old 
>   result of Wiener showing that when $d < N^{0.25}$ RSA is insecure. We hope our 
>   approach can be used to eventually improve the bound to $d < N^{0.5}$.

https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/lowRSAexp.html