# Formal security-definition reference

Tags: reference-request, chosen-plaintext-attack, security-definition, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Is there a reference where all common formal security-definitions are summarized (such as OW-CPA, IND-CPA, IND-CCA1, IND-CCA2, EUF-CMA and so on)? I need a PUBLISHED reference (paper, book) which would be possible to handily quote.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Did you search for this site? They are answered!.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/36960 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44188/36960

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy explanation of "IND-" security notions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/easy-explanation-of-ind-security-notions)

Comment: Thank' you, but I'm more interested in a PUBLISHED reference (a book or a paper), which would be possible to quote.

Comment: I am sure you can find most of those definitions on [Katz and Lindell's introductory book](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/imc.html) and I am almost sure that you can find them in almost all basic books on crypto...

Comment: Another introductory reference: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/gb.html

Comment: See also: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316

Comment: This book: "A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography
Dan Boneh and Victor Shoup"  has everything about you need about formal security.